# how to pass value from java to flex?

Tags: java, apache-flex, jakarta-ee, flex3, flex4.5

I have a code of JDBC which connects to database,returns the result in `ResultSet` which fetches two columns `emp_id` and `emp_name` with different rows every time. So rows can not be constant at all. I just want to pass that result to flex side in array collection. I do not know what to use or how? Somebody guide me to use `HashMap`, but I do not know how to use it. I am not able to use `HashMap` and `ArrayList` please help me.

Can anybody give me a code how I can save that result in `ArrayList` at java side from `ResultSet`?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please format the post correctly !!!

Comment: Is it a web application ? Have you heard of [blazeds](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/) ?

Comment: *can any body give me code how i can save that result in array list at java side from rslt.?* Just iterate through the resultset and add each element to a `List` or `Map` !! There are tons of tutorials to get yourself acquainted about that ...

Comment: @noob unchained : can u provide me some code

Comment: Map<String, Object> include = null;
 include.put("emp-id", rslt.getString("emp_id"));
 include.put("emp-name", rslt.getString("emp_name"));
System.out.println("emp-name" + rslt.getString("emp_name")

Comment: but its showing error at console ...i m using this code

Comment: Posted some code as answer, please go through that !!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
List<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
Map<String,String> include = null;
while (rs.next()) {
     include = new HashMap<String,String>();
     String empID = rs.getString("emp_id");
     String empName = rs.getString("emp_name");
     include.put("emp_id",empID);
     include.put("emp_name",empName);
     list.add(include);
}
```

Retrieve those values as an `ArrayCollection` of Flex `Object` at flex side.

Comment: so in my code i just write textinput which i hve created dynamically and set the value of textinput.label = program.list[i].emp_name(i is for iteration of length of array collection).Program is my VO(value object) .text input is created but its showing nothing ..it displaying nothing.plz help

Comment: hi can u tell me how to iterate over this list in java and fetch the different vlaue when i am getting this back from flex side ... i am unable to seprate the vlaue of emp
_id or emp_name